# Hibernate RESTful webservices in NetBeans

Tags: web-services, hibernate, rest, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is it possible to create RESTful Web Service using Hibernate in Netbeans 7.4?

I could see wizard to create RESTful Web Service using Persistence, but would like to know how it can be integrated with Hibernate?

Appreciate any help or insight.

**Edit 1**

I would like to know what I did is the correct method of generating RESTful web services using Hibernate.

First I generated Hibernate Entity classes using NetBeans and then I created RESTful services from Entity classes. So does this creates RESTful Web Services with Hibernate? I could see AbstractFacade classes that is almost like DAO classes

**Edit 2**

Screen shot for selecting RESTful Web Service from Entity classes

[image]

Comment: What is your notion of "correct"? REST is an architecture style, not a standard. There is no one right way to build a RESTful service, but there are many ways to build a service that do not conform to the constraints of a RESTful architecture.

Comment: is there a way to do exactly this with spring tool suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build a truly RESTful service, you need to build up a link relation architecture. You're going to need more than Hibernate or Netbeans to do that.

I recommend using the milestone Spring Data REST in conjunction with Hibernate's JPA implementation and Spring HATEOAS. See [Spring Restbucks](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks) as an example which brings all these technologies together.

Comment: Jonathan I would like to clarify doubt here whether what I have done is correct or not. First I generated Hibernate Entity classes using NetBeans and then I created RESTful services from Entity classes. So does this creates RESTful Web Services with Hibernate? I could see AbstractFacade class that is almost like DAO classes.

Comment: How did you create RESTful services from Entity classes? Is this something specific to NetBeans? I find it very unlikely that a wizard is really going to create an adequate RESTful service for you. It may serialize your entity objects into JSON representations, but simply doing so does not a RESTful service make.

Comment: Jonathan I have attached a screen shot in my question of generating RESTful services from Entity classes in NetBeans

Comment: I haven't used it, but it's likely a "RESTful web service" in that it fits the buzzword definition of REST (i.e., RPC using JSON over HTTP). That may be fine for your needs, but you asked if that is "correct." According to Roy Fielding, the "Father of REST," such a system is not RESTful.

Comment: Because it is using JSON instead of HTTP? I didn't quite understand your point of RPC using JSON over HTTP. When I looked the classes I understand that there are HTTP methods with return data in both XML and JSON format. e.g. `@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})` So does this mean it is still not HTTP REST to  call it as RESTful web services?

Comment: Neither XML nor JSON natively provide a way to specify link relations, and the hypermedia constraint of REST is not optional. You'd have to return a media type such as `application/atom+xml` or `application/hal+json`. If you don't return navigable links, you are in effect doing RPC.